# Stored Procedure with dependent table not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How we can retrieve all stored procedures from a Microsoft SQL server with its dependent table not exist in the database?

I just explain it more....

I have a database with hundreds of tables and stored procedures. In the mean while of developing time i just add many more tables and drop some previous tables form database, but stored procedures depend on this table are not. The result is that when i generate script of above database and try to restore it in another one its make error due to the no existing of the tables.

Answer (score 3):

The following query should give you what you are after.

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(sed.referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name, 
        sed.referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'P'
and not exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                where table_name = referenced_entity_name)
and referenced_id is null
```

It uses sys.objects to find stored procedures and joins to sys.sql_expression_dependencies to find dependencies for those SPs. It then filters the dependencies based on whether or not the table exists in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

More information on finding dependencies can be found on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345404%28v=sql.120%29.aspx.

Note that `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` only exists in SQL Server 2008 and upwards. You don't state which version you are using but if you are using 2005 you will need to use `sys.sql_dependencies` instead of `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`. Unfortunately it's not a straight swap as the columns are different but again more information can be found on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Good SQL statement.. one remark: When a Stored Procedure calls an existing stored procedure it also shows in this list.

Answer (score 0):

Dear you are not mention your sqlserver version.

But you can achieve by 2 query

```
-- first query to get all procedure name
    SELECT routine_name, routine_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' order by ROUTINE_NAME asc

--you can loop of above and pass the each procedure name to this second query. If zero return , then no dependency
    SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbname.procedureName', 'OBJECT');
```

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1294/listing-sql-server-object-dependencies/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms345404.aspx

[Stored procedure dependencies in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228886/stored-procedure-dependencies-in-sql-server-management-studio)

http://sqlhints.com/2013/05/06/how-to-find-referenceddependent-objects-like-table-function-etc-of-a-stored-procedurefunction-in-sql-server/

[Determining the dependencies of a stored procedure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631177/determining-the-dependencies-of-a-stored-procedure)